# Why are Cardinal Invariants called Invariants?

Tags: set-theory

Just the title question. Why are the cardinal invariants of the continuum (for example: $\mathfrak m$, $\mathfrak p$, $\mathrm{add}(\mathcal L)$, $\mathfrak b$ etc) called invariants? I know they are also called cardinal characteristics, and I get that name, but in which regard are they "invariant"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **informal** idea is that they are invariants of *models of set theory* (or initial segments, e.g. $H_{\omega_2}$s, thereof); e.g. given a model $M$, we can ask what values $M$ assigns to $\mathfrak{d}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ (say), and potentially use this to distinguish $M$ from other models of set theory.

Of course this is actually pretty dangerous: unless we restrict attention to *well-founded* models we have no way to compare the ordinals of two different models. And even when we restrict attention to well-founded models, we're usually thinking of our invariants as taking values in *cardinals* rather than ordinals, so it becomes slippery to compare these across models which don't have the same cardinals. Consider for example a pair of models $M,N\models\mathsf{ZFC+CH}$ with additionally $M\models\omega_1^N<\omega_1$; do $M$ and $N$ assign the same value ("$\omega_1$") to the standard cardinal characteristics of the continuum?

In my opinion, especially given the importance of collapsing cardinals in studying cardinal characteristics, the right way to fix this is to look instead at the **syntactic versions** of these invariants. E.g. it's not the value of $\mathfrak{d}$ or $\mathfrak{b}$ itself in a model $M$, but rather *the truth value of the sentence $\mathfrak{b}<\mathfrak{d}$ in that model*, which is the invariant: in the above example, $M$ and $N$ would indeed "have the same invariants" assigned to all the usual *pairs of* cardinal characteristics. But ultimately, the intuition is simply that **cardinal characteristics provide a partial description of (an initial segment of) a model of set theory**, and they are invariant up to isomorphism as usual.

Comment: I feel like I've heard 'cardinal invariant' referring to just any property of anything that is characterized by a cardinality, e.g. the weight is a cardinal invariant of a topological space. And in this case, e.g., the covering number is a cardinal invariant of an ideal. I also think 'it's an odd choice of words for property' makes more sense than it being something characterizing a model because of the awkwardness you mention in this answer.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Note that the question is focusing specifically on cardinal characteristics of the continuum, not general cardinal invariants.

Comment: Thank you Noah! So, to summarize, I could say that $\mathfrak b$ and $\mathfrak d$ are not really invariant, but their relation $\mathfrak b\le\mathfrak d$ is invariant in any model of set theory, while the relation $\mathfrak b<\mathfrak d$ could be invariant only for some models, etc...

Comment: @NoahSchweber I understand that. What I'm trying to say is I think that, etymologically speaking, the usage 'cardinal invariant' here is the same as in the general sense, referring to cardinal invariants of ideals (and things like $\mathfrak p$ that can't be expressed that way, just got lumped in). The Bartoszynski chapter of the handbook of set theory seems to support that view (though Blass's chapter before that says 'characteristics' was introduced because people complained 'they aren't invariant').